# on button click display a label

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, button, runatserver

I am trying to implement a simple functionality. Basically, it is a search bar. On button click a label should appear with some predefined text+ the search term. Here is my aspx code..

```
<section class="webdesigntuts-workshop">
    <form id="form1" runat="server">            
        <asp:TextBox type="search" name="search" id="sform" placeholder="What are you looking for?" runat="server" />       
        <asp:label id="searchResultLabel" runat="server" Visible="false" />     
        <button id="lookup" onclick="lookup_Click"  runat="server">Search</button>
    </form>
</section>
```

Here is my aspx.cs code:

```
protected void lookup_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            String query = sform.Text;
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(query))
            {
                searchResultLabel.Text = "You are looking up the term" + query;
                searchResultLabel.Visible = true;
            }
        }
```

As of now, on button clock i do not see anything happening. I have added break points but the line of control does not seem to come to .cs code on button click.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `onClick` on a regular HTML `<button>` element will look for a *JavaScript* event, rather than the code-behind/server-side event you want.

To reference the server-side event instead, you can do either of the following:

**1.** Change your `<button>` to an `<asp:Button>` instead.

```
<asp:Button id="lookup" onclick="lookup_Click"  runat="server">Search</asp:Button>
```

(*Note: If you're referencing this button by ID anywhere on the front-end, you'll want to add the property `ClientIdMode="static"` to ensure that the ID is not rewritten when the element is rendered.*)

**2.** Change `onclick="lookup_Click"` to `onServerClick="lookup_Click"`.